# Visualforce Page as the Default Layout of an Object (Standard/Custom)

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

Is it possible to make a visualforce page as a replacement for the standard page layout for viewing Contacts record detail page for instance? I'm not talking about inline Visualforce page addition to the Contact layout. I meant to use the whole vsp as the standard view of said object. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply add a Standard Controller to the page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" ...
```

And then you can go to Setup > Customize > Contacts > Buttons, Links, and Actions, and edit the View button. All users will then see the new Visualforce page when viewing a contact.

See [Overriding Buttons, Links, and Tabs with Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_customize_override.htm) for more information.

Comment: Gee, I was dissecting the Contact Layout for this and it was in another setting all along. That helped, thanks a bunch!